# How To Transfer data from a python web application to a java desktop applaction

Tags: java, python, port, web-applications

I want some help on a way to transfer data from a python web application to a java desktop application.

What I am doing is having java listen on a port and receive data. But I have no idea how I would send data from python to an open port on a server.

What my question is how would I send data from a python web app to an open port on a computer. And would there be any problems like data types and any other things?

Comment: If you know how to make a connection between the two you might want to look at a platform independent medium for relaying that data. Some might be JSON, XML, CORBA, etc. Depending on the data a simple byte stream might be adequate. What sort of data are you transfering?

Comment: @Rig I am transferring string and integers and an index to associate each with an other

Comment: Does the Python server have to be HTTP?  I assume you need to "Push" data to the Java application?  Otherwise why not just pull from python on some interval or at startup.  Can you use Long polling/HTTP server push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really large question as there are *many* ways to send data back and forth between server (your java app) and client (your python app).

Your situation is not quite clear (what exactly is your "python web application"?), but you may want to look into [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/).  XML-RPC is extremely simple to use and set up, and takes care of "problems like data types and any other things".  You basically just set up some functions on your server that the client can call, and have python call them.  Arguments are neatly wrapped up by teh client and unwrapped by the server.  Return values are the same.  It is a simple and clean interface.

For python making calls to the server, you want to use the [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) module.

To set up an XMLRPC server in java, you have [many](http://www.xmlrpc.com/directory/1568/implementations) [options](http://www.google.ca/search?q=java%20xmlrpc%20server).  I'm not a Java guy, but I'm sure it is quite simple on that side as well.

There are many good xml-rpc tutorials.  [Here is one](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xmlrpclib/index.html) that covers client and server in python.

Like I said earlier, there are MANY options available to you.  XML-RPC is a good and simple way to get your feet wet, without really limiting you very much (eg: it has built in fault handling).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will try that it looks promising

Comment: This is probably the solution I would pick. It's just too easy and fits well in a lot of cases. Its situational but this is adequate in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a platform independent data format -- xml, json, yaml, ascii txt, ... -- to represent numbers, you have really nothing to worry about.

If you can not afford the inefficiencies of above, then a binary protocol is required.

Java uses network byte ordering (or Big Endian).  Python uses the native host byte ordering, OR, you can specify the byte ordering.  Here you want to [specify Big Endian (sec 7.3.2.1)](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) in writing your numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use sockets in python too and send it to the java server. Java does not know that the end client is python, what it reads is just data(bytes). I have done this, and it works seamlessly.

See the python's struct module for more details on converting datatypes